# Return the number of times that the string "code" appears anywhere in the given string, except we'll accept any

Tags: python-3.x

problem: 
Return the number of times that the string "code" appears anywhere in the given string, except we'll accept any letter for the 'd', so "cope" and "cooe" count.
as above mentioned problem i tried with below code gave me error.

```
def count_code(str):
  count=0
  for i in range(len(str)-3):
    if 'code' == str[i:4] or 'cope' in str[i:4] or 'cooe' in str[i:4]:
       count +=1
  return count
```

while other code specified below given correct answer. but i am not understanding what is wrong with my frist code.

```
def count_code(str):
  count=0
  for i in range(len(str)-3):
    if str[i:i+2] == 'co' and str[i+3]=='e':
      count +=1
  return count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here: `if 'code' == str[i:4] or 'cope' in str[i:4] or 'cooe' in str[i:4]:`

The slicing syntax in this case is `iterable[start:stop]`. By doing `str[i:4]`, any time the value of `i` is greater than 4 you'll get an error. What I think you meant to do was `str[i:i+4]` (which would still not be correct).

Answer (score 1):

1. You are checking for `code/cope/cooe`, but any letter means there are 23 more possible variations you're not checking for.
2. It should be :

   ```
   if 'code' == str[i:i+4] or 'cope' in str[i:i+4] or 'cooe' in str[i:i+4]:
       count +=1
   ```

So that when you are a character **i**, you check whether the 4 next characters match. Right now you're only checking whether character number **i** to character number 4 (fixed) is a match.

Comment: wow! Thanks. I didn't notice that thing.

Answer (score 1):

The specific cause of your error and the immediate fixes required have been correctly identified in other answers. However, I think your code needs a more fundamental redesign. You are "re-inventing the wheel" by trying to write an algorithm to count occurrences of substrings, when it would be much easier to count them with an existing solution from the standard library.

The `.count` method can be used to count occurrences of a substring. Since there are 26 letters which `co_e` could occur with, there are 26 different substrings you need to count, so it would make sense to use a loop to count them all:

```py
def count_code(s):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    total = 0
    for letter in alphabet:
        total += s.count('co' + letter + 'e')
    return total
```

Or using the `sum` function:

```py
def count_code(s):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    return sum(s.count('co' + letter + 'e') for letter in alphabet)
```

Another simple solution is to use a regex `co[a-z]e` to find the occurrences, and `len` to count them:

```py
import re

def count_code(s):
    return len(re.findall('co[a-z]e', s))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good use case for a regex.

```
import re

string = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
code
Vivamus ac justo velit.
cope
Aliquam consectetur nisl nec vestibulum luctus.
cooe
Quisque aliquet tortor id varius mollis.
cole
Sed ipsum libero, facilisis eget mollis et, maximus vitae ipsum.
come
"""
matches = re.findall(r"co[a-zA-Z]e", string)
print(len(matches))
```

Comment: Testing for whitespace isn't necessary - the problem asks to count how many times it *"appears anywhere in the given string"*, not necessarily surrounded by whitespace or word boundaries. But also `.` will match non-letter characters, and the problem only says *"we'll accept any letter"*.

Answer (score 1):

Return the number of times that the string "code" appears anywhere in the given string, except we'll accept any letter for the 'd', so "cope" and "cooe" count.

```
def count_code(str):
  c1=0
  for i in range(len(str)-3):
    if str[i:i+2] =='co' and str[i+3]=='e':
      c1 +=1
  return c1
```